# How to get a Mootools event on an element passed to mako by cherrypy to work?

Tags: events, mootools, cherrypy

So I have in index.py:

```
class Test:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return mylookup.get_template('test.html').render(item="<div id='blah'>test</div>")
```

And in test.html:

```
<script>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $('blah').addEvent('click', function() {
      alert('success');
  });
});
</script>
```

When clicking on that element nothing happens. Any ideas?

% if item:
    ${item}
% endif

Comment: do you get any errors? does the html render ok? the javascript here is fine - the question is, does $("blah") return true at the time domready fires? try to add _if (!$("blah")) alert("fail!");_

Comment: I'll do some more investigating if it should work. It doesn't flare any errors, so maybe it's something else. Thanks.